# Javascript Error ":" Expected

Tags: javascript

Helo all im setting  JSON-like data format to ne used by a JS libray called fusioncharts.

At the bottom is a section called "Data" and in there the error is happening at the second object: `totalFundedValue`

Ok here is a snippet of my rendered HTML:

```
var totalFunded =  '109321734.06';

var totalFundedValue;
var totalFundedLabel;
var totalFundedText;


if (totalFunded != null)  
{
totalFundedLabel.push({ "label": "Funded",});
totalFundedValue.push({"value": "109321734.06"});
 totalFundedText.push({"toolText": "$109,321,734.06"});
}


"data":[{
    totalFundedLabel
    totalFundedValue
    totalFundedText
  }
]
```

JS:

```
var totalFunded =  '${totalFunded}';

var totalFundedValue;
var totalFundedLabel;
var totalFundedText;


if (totalFunded != null)  
{
totalFundedLabel.push({ "label": "Funded",});
totalFundedValue.push({"value": <tld-msst:fc-value var="${totalFunded}"/>,});
totalFundedText.push({"toolText": "<fmt:formatNumber value='${totalFunded}' type='currency' groupingUsed='true' />"});
}
```

just for clarification, this is what it looks like without using the push methods:

```
   data: [{
    "label":"Funded",
    "value":"${totalFunded}",
    "toolText": "<fmt:formatNumber value='${totalFunded}' type='currency' groupingUsed='true' />"
  },
```

Comment: That isn't valid Javascript.

Comment: And whats your question? You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You cannot assign values using the colon outside of an object declaration, i.e. `data:[{'label' : 'funded'}]` instead, you need to use `var data = [{'label' : 'funded'}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like everyone addressed the 'comma' issue. There's some other issues, such as:

1. You can't just push to empty variables, it'll throw an undefined. They'd have to be declared like `var totalFundedLabel = [];`. This probably isn't the right situation for a `push`

Have you considered using an old-fashioned object literal?

`var totalObj = {};`

`var totalFunded =  '109321734.06';`

`if (totalFunded != null)`
`{`

```
totalObj.label = "Funded";
totalObj.value = "109321734.06";

totalObj.toolText = "$109,321,734.06";
```

`}`

`console.log('{"data": [' + JSON.stringify(totalObj) + ']}');`

`// outputs this: {"data": [{"label":"Funded","value":"109321734.06","toolText":"$109,321,734.06"}]}`

This works fine for me, and builds the requested string. Here's the JS Fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/98XXN/1/

Does this help?

Comment: p.s. I think the down-votes @Doc Holiday got were unnecessary. He's just on here to get help. Way to go guys :/

Comment: @ Mike LeDoux I appreciate your help very much.  This is a minor bug for an otherwise great app I have setup so thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
totalFundedLabel.push({ "label": "Funded",});
```

To:

```
totalFundedLabel.push({ "label": "Funded"});
```

Remove the trailing comma.

Comment: Trailing comma, you mean :D

Comment: It needs that to separate the objects whenb they are used at the bottom ie: ` totalFundedLabel
        totalFundedValue
        totalFundedText`

Comment: @DocHoliday Nopes. You don't need it. :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I removed all the trailing commas but I still get that JS error at `totalFundedValue`?????

Comment: Im saying removing the trailing comma did not solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

You still get that error because "data" is an array with an object inside, and a object always expect a pointer and a value.

```
"data":[{
    totalFundedLabel
    totalFundedValue
    totalFundedText
  }
]
```

and what you really want to do is:

```
"data":[{
    totalFundedLabel: 'value1',
    totalFundedValue: 'value2',
    totalFundedText: 'value3'
  }
]
```

i hope this was helpfull!